# VB6 Format equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, vb6-migration

I am converting some VB6 code to C# and am having a problem duplicating certain functionality. I have a string representation of a number ex.6000 and a format specifier of ex. ###0.000.

VB6 Example:

```
Format(number, "########0.000") = "6.000"
```

I am having trouble finding the C# equivalent to duplicate this functionality. The methods I have tried with `ToString()` but they are more for formatting the actual number rather than more of an overlay format like VB6 is doing.

C# Example:

```
number.ToString("########0.000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) = 6000.000
```

Comment: Maybe divide 6000 by 1000 first?

Comment: @leppie - I've considered that but this can actually be variable length and I'd like to avoid having to figure out the divisor every time if possible.

Comment: I think the format specifiers in `ToString` are different from those in `Format`, I think you need to use `"0,0.00"`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx for details

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to programmatically convert VB6 Formatting strings to .NET Formatting strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072490/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-convert-vb6-formatting-strings-to-net-format)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think you should simply revisit your inputs and numeric specifiers to be more appropriate, but: you could cheat with:

```
string s = number.ToString(@"########0\.000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The `\.` is now **not** the decimal point specifier, but a literal. Horrible horrible answer. Please don't do it.

Comment: yea i'm thinking revisiting is the only way to go. I really don't want to "cheat" but was rather hoping for an equivalent function. I've seen this functionality in XSLT also, so I was hoping there was a C# equivalent that maybe I was just missing :/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "FormatNumber" function instead

Comment: I believe this is a VB method which I know can be referenced via VisualBasic inclusion, but was hoping there was a similar C# function