# equivalent for vb6.Format function in vb.net without using Microsoft.Visualbasic.Compatibility.dll

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to programmatically convert VB6 Formatting strings to .NET Formatting strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072490/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-convert-vb6-formatting-strings-to-net-format)

during migration from vb6 to vb.net the Format$(1234567, "###,###,###,###") function is converted to vb6.Format(1234567,"###,###,###,###") function, which is defined in  Microsoft.Visualbasic.Compatibility.dll.

I dont want to use  Microsoft.Visualbasic.Compatibility.dll. Is there any equivalent for this in .NET.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [.ToString(string) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dim value As Integer = 1234567
value.ToString("###,###,###,###")
```

or the [String.Format Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which uses [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
String.Format("{0:###,###,###,###}", 1234567)
```

Comment: Hi,
The output for the above methods is 12,34,567 but the output of vb6.Format(1234567,"###,###,###,###") is 1,234,567.

Comment: @user1943176 It prints out correctly on my Computer, double check your format string. it is probably ###,###,##,### instead of ###,###,###,###

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its working in my friend's system, but not in mine. we both have windows7 OS and same framework of .NET. I don't know the what is the reason for this.