# How to format numbers with different decimal places to have leading zeros

Tags: vb.net, vb6, format

I'm migrating an old software in vb6 to vb.net
I want to be able to add leading zeros to numbers (but these numbers might haver decimal places or not)

In vb6 this is done by:

```
Format(number, "00000")
```

in vb.net this would translate to

```
String.Format("{0:D5}", number)
```

The problem is, this only works if the variable number is an Integer... but its not its an object

Sometimes it is an Integer, other it is a Double

Is there anyway to emulate the VB6 behavior and take care of integers and doubles with the same code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [equivalent for vb6.Format function in vb.net without using Microsoft.Visualbasic.Compatibility.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133762/equivalent-for-vb6-format-function-in-vb-net-without-using-microsoft-visualbasic)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate (at least not to that question) because there are decimal places involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ToString` method with the appropriate format string.

`number.ToString("00000.##")`

Put the appropriate number of `#`s according to how many decimal places you want to show (if the number has decimal places).

For example:

```
Dim foo as double = 123456
Dim foo2 as double = 1234.56
Dim foo3 as double = 123.456
Console.WriteLine(foo.ToString("00000000.##"))
Console.WriteLine(foo2.ToString("00000000.##"))
Console.WriteLine(foo3.ToString("00000000.##"))
```

Will result in:

```
00123456
00001234.56
00000123.46
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont know if the number of decimal cases varies... (its old code)

I've found this alternative:

```
CDbl(number).ToString().PadLeft(5, "0")
```