# VB.Net Replacing the usage of VB6.Format

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I need to format times to be like this:

Inputs to the function look like

```
Input        Output
01:20        0120
0120         0120
01:20:23     0120
120          0120
01           0100
1            0100
```

We used to use VB6.Format, but cannot any longer. How would I use something such as String.Format to replace this code?

We would use something like this previously

```
TimeFormatVariable = VB6.Format(OriginalTimeInput, "hhnn")
```

Comment: Your input looks like bad strings.  How do you know `01` is one hour and not one minute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to programmatically convert VB6 Formatting strings to .NET Formatting strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072490/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-convert-vb6-formatting-strings-to-net-format)

Comment: In VB6 format doesn't work that way.  For instance "0120" produces "0000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple function that will take a string formatted like any of your inputs and the format you specify, and returns a string formatted like your outputs:

```
Private Function FormatTime(Input As String, Format as String) As String
    Dim TimeFormat As New DateTime
    Dim GoodString As Boolean = DateTime.TryParse(Input, TimeFormat)
    If Not GoodString Then
        If Integer.TryParse(Input, vbNull) Then
            If Input.Length > 2 Then
                Input = Input.PadLeft(4, "0"c)
                TimeFormat = New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, Integer.Parse(Input.Substring(0, 2)), Integer.Parse(Input.Substring(2)), 0)
            Else
                TimeFormat = New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, Integer.Parse(Input.PadLeft(2, "0"c).Substring(0, 2)), 0, 0)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return TimeFormat.ToString(Format)
End Function
```

This does simple validating as well.  It checks for proper time format and if not, if all characters are digits

Your statement would look like this:

`TimeFormatVariable = FormatTime(OriginalTimeInput, "hhmm")

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your OriginalTimeInput is either DateTime or Date format:

```
OriginalTimeInput.ToString("hhmm")
```

Should do it.

Comment: The problem with that is that it comes in as a string.