# Adding a "-" with String.Format VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I am trying to get an item such as WO123000 to come out as WO-123000. Here is the code, but it isn't working for me.

```
WorkOrder = String.Format("{0:##-######}", Trim(WorkOrderNum))
```

This is where WorkOrderNum is WO123000. This error stems from VB6.Format migration issues.

Comment: Why should .NET split your string `WO123000` automatically?

Comment: I am just trying to get the string to add a dash after the first characters.

Comment: They can be any characters. Not just letters as the first two.

Comment: Are you trying to format the number too, or is it reliable?  E.g. are you trying to turn `"WO1"` into `"WO-00001"`?

Comment: Nothing that String.SubString() should not be able to fix.  Or simply [keep using the VB6 Format function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072490/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-convert-vb6-formatting-strings-to-net-format/4072859#4072859).

Comment: It is already reliable and handle by another function.

Comment: That is not an option @HansPassant

Comment: What did the VB6 code look like. I doubt that `Format(WorkOrderNum,"##-######")` would have worked for that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the length of the string remains constant:

```
Dim WorkOrderNum = "WO123000"   
Dim testStr As String = String.Format("{0}-{1}", WorkOrderNum.SubString(0, 2), WorkOrderNum.SubString(2, 6))    
Console.WriteLine(testStr)

'outputs WO-123000
```

Although I'm sure there's a better way of doing this which should include error handling etc this was just a demo!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to format the number itself, the following should give you what you want:

```
WorkOrder = Trim(WorkOrderNum).Insert(2, "-")
```

If the input varies a lot (as your comment states it does) then you'll want to extract the number first, then format it:

```
string WorkOrder = "abc123";
int woNum;
if (int.TryParse(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(WorkOrder, @"\d+").Value, out woNum))
{
    return String.Format("WO-{0:00000}", woNum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that WO stands for 'Work Order'. This would suggest to me that the first two letters of every work order will be WO. This means that you can just do the following instead of formatting:

```
Dim WorkOrderNum As String = "WO123000"
Dim OutputOrderNum As String = WorkOrderNum.Replace("WO", "WO-")
```

Hope this helped,

Rodit

Comment: But, it doesn't have to be. If they wanted, it could be 11111111

Comment: Then it is like formatting a random string @user2311799