# VB.Net VB6.Format() Issues after converting

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

Having some issues after running a tool to convert the VB6.Format() to VS 2008 code. We had this statement:

```
VB6.Format(InVariable, szFormatMask))
```

That was converted to this:

```
InVariable.ToString(szFormatMask)
```

The issue being that now, when we call our function it has having the issue that it cannot convert a String = "" to an Integer value. InVariable is an object, and szFormatMask is a string in our function. Do you have any suggestions as to not cause this issue any longer?

Comment: What is the exact type of `InVariable`? (so even though it's cast as an `System.Object`, what is it really?)

Comment: In this instance, it is a double being sent to the function.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2187770/11683

Comment: Didn't really help me at all..

Answer (score 0):

Add a check for the empty string and change accordingly:

```
If szFormatMask = "" Then szFormatMask = "G"
Return InVariable.ToString( szFormatMask )
```

The 'G' format-string value is special in that is specifies the output is the "General" number format.

(A brief word on code-style: please avoid Hungarian notation, e.g. the `In` and `sz` prefixes, and name local variables and parameters using lowercase `camelCase`, as uppercase `CamelCase` is reserved for type members like methods and properties.

Comment: Now, I am getting Conversion from type "G" to type Integer exception is not valid.