# How to migrate string format function with "!@@@" from vb6.0 to vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I'm migrating source from vb6.0 to vb.net and am struggling with this format function:

`VB6.Format(text, "!@@@@@@@@@")`

`VB6.Format(text, "00000")`

I don't understand the meaning  of `"!@@@@@@@@@"` and `"00000"`, and how to do the equivalent in VB.Net. Thanks

Comment: [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) is for the VBA version of that `Format` function but they work the same way, so you can get all you need from there. Once you understand what the existing format specifiers mean, you should replace that method with the standard .NET `String.Format` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB6 Format function: analog in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116244/vb6-format-function-analog-in-net)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```vb
VB6.Format(text, "!@@@@@@@@@")
```

indicates that the specified text should be left-aligned within a nine-character string. Using standard .NET functionality, that would look like this:

```vb
String.Format("{0,-9}", text)
```

or, using the newer string interpolation, like this:

```vb
$"{text,-9}"
```

The second on is a little bit trickier. It's indicating that the specified text should be formatted as a number, zero-padded to five digits. In .NET, only actual numbers can be formatted as numbers. `Strings` containing digit characters are not numbers. You could convert the `String` to a number and then format it:

```vb
String.Format("{0:00000}", CInt(text))
```

or:

```vb
String.Format("{0:D5}", CInt(text))
```

If you were going to do that then it's simpler to just call `ToString` on the number:

```vb
CInt(text).ToString("D5")
```

If you don't want to do the conversion then you can pad the `String` explicitly instead:

```vb
text.PadLeft(5, "0"c)
```

Comment: In VB6 `Format(text, "00000")` works on numeric data-types only and is a no-op for strings i.e. returns `text` unchanged.

Comment: @wqw, I've never used VB6 and was not aware of that. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @wqw - that is true only when the string contains non-numerics. When the string is numeric characters, then the formatting is performed.  For example, `Format("12q", "00000")` returns `"12q"`, while `Format("12", "00000")` returns `"00012"`.

Comment: @MarkL, fortunately, I have not yet updated my answer.

Comment: @MarkL Nice catch! By now it must be obvious `String.Format("{0:00000}", CInt(text))` is not the same as `VB6.Format(text, "00000")`.