# VBA equivalent User Defined String formats in TSQL?

Tags: vba, t-sql, ms-access

VBA allows for [user-defined string formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications#user-defined-string-formats) in `Format()`. I am particularly interested in replicating the placeholder characters, `@` and `!` in SQL Server (*using its `Format()` function? - open to alternatives*).

My use case requires a mix of characters and numbers stored as a `Variant` type in VBA.

With `@` and `!` placeholder characters, here is what I would like to mimic from VBA in SQL Server.

**VBA**:
`Format(12DFR89, "!@@-@-@@@@")`

- Output: 12-D-FR89

Comment: `FORMAT`, in T-SQL, is for formatting a non-string type value to a specific string representation. For example formatting a date to something like `dd/MM/yyyy` or a numerical value to value leading zero's and thousand separators like `#,000`. It doesn't format string type data types. *Really*, however, any formatting should be done in the presentation layer; it's not the role of the RDBMS.

Comment: If you really want to do it, you will have to import a CLR assembly to your server that does either https://stackoverflow.com/a/2187770/11683 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072859/11683.

Comment: Are you asking how to replicate the *specific* `"!@@-@-@@@@"` format?

Comment: @AlexK. Yes.  :-)

Comment: @Larnu thank you, and yes I see your point on the role of the RDBMS; however, for what I am trying to accomplish handling it this way would not affect anything outside of the query I am trying to run; I'm only going to use this a few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your asking about reproducing the fixed format `"!@@-@-@@@@"` you can do this a with UDF that replicates the VBA behaviour:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CustomFormat(@VALUE VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @MAX_LENGTH INT = 7

    SET @VALUE = RIGHT(@VALUE + ISNULL(RIGHT(REPLICATE('?', @MAX_LENGTH - LEN(@VALUE)), @MAX_LENGTH), ''), @MAX_LENGTH)

    RETURN CONCAT( 
        LEFT(@VALUE, 2),
        '-',
        SUBSTRING(@VALUE, 3, 1),
        '-',
        SUBSTRING(@VALUE, 4, @MAX_LENGTH)
    )
END
GO
```

Example:

```
SELECT
    test,
    dbo.CustomFormat(test)
FROM ( VALUES
    ('1'), ('12'), ('123'), ('1234'), ('12345'), ('123456'), ('1234567'), ('12345678'), ('123456789'), ('1234567890')
) AS T(test)
```

For:

```
test
1           1?-?-????
12          12-?-????
123         12-3-????
1234        12-3-4???
12345       12-3-45??
123456      12-3-456?
1234567     12-3-4567
12345678    23-4-5678
123456789   34-5-6789
1234567890  45-6-7890
```

(Replace `'?'` with `' '` in the function to get spaces)

Comment: Thank you, Alex. This is a helpful solution that will be very convenient when needing to create lookups in a pinch from SQL Server instead of Access.